# HttpPost not working in jellybean with Thread

Tags: android, mysql, http, http-post

I am trying to create connection with database and it's ok in gigerbread 2.3.6 and not in higher than jellybean os.

Here is my code -

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               select();

           }                        
    }).start();
```

Select Method - (I get id from edittext)

```
public void select()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

String id="1";
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));

    try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yangoninnovation.com/mmuniteddbphp/conn.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        txvstartstatus.setText("connected ...");
}
    catch(Exception e)
{

        txvstartstatus.setText("No Internet connection: ");
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

            String re2;
            re2=result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(":"));
            re2=re2.substring(2, re2.lastIndexOf('"'));

            txvstartstatus.setText(re2);


}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        txvstartstatus.setText("No Internet connection: ");
}     
}
```

I can't control to connect in higher android version. Please kindly help me. My select() works successfully in lower versions. How can I solve it . Thanks in advance. I'm stacked about a month with this problem. Hopefully you can help that !